# How to use ajax to pass a variable to a php file using POST method?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have modified the code

to POST  prodID  to ProductsList.php

```
  // its a dynamically generated drop menu
   while($rowmnu2=mysql_fetch_assoc($resulmnusub2))
    {
       echo '<li><a  id="'.$rowmnu2['liid'].'" href="#" onclick="passto(this.id)">'.$rowmnu2['title'].'</a></li>
';
    }
```

and here is my ajax function :

```
function passto(val){
//window.location.href="ProductsList.php?idd=" + val;
 $.ajax({
    url: 'ProductsList.php', 
    type: "POST",
    data: ({prodID: val}),
    success: function(data){
        //or if the data is JSON
        window.location.href="ProductsList.php";
    }
}); 
}
```

the passed element to the function is an integer

in the ProductsList.php  I have

```
<?php 

if(!$_POST['prodID']) die("There is no such product!");

echo $_POST['prodID'];


?>
```

and I get There is no such product!   while there should be an INT #

why is that ?

any one knows?  all the bellow suggestions are not responding correctly

Comment: The ' onclick="passto(this)"' is sending a whole DOM object to the function. You will need to drill down to the actual piece of data that you are wanting.

Comment: Try Replace `data: {prodID:val},` to  `data: {prodID:val.id},`

Comment: @jeff no it doesn't, I get just the ID number when I alert the val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behavior is normal because you are requesting ProductsList.php twice. the first time with an AJAX request using `$.ajax`. for that time the id is sent correctly. The problem is that you request ProductsList.php again just after AJAX complete using `window.location.href="ProductsList.php";` without sending anything. So the result is as expected, a page printing `There is no such product!`

You can fix the problem by replacing `window.location.href="ProductsList.php";` by this one :

```
$('body').html(data);
```

or any other instruction to use properly the returned data.

You can either use my edited code or just edit yours :

```
echo '<li ><a  id="'.$rowmnu2['link'].'" href="#">'.$rowmnu2['title'].'</a></li>';
```

JS part :

```
$('a').click(function() {

    var val = $( this ).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ProductsList.php",
        data: {prodID:val},
        complete:function(){
            $('body').html(data);  
        } 
   });
});
```

Comment: i have added  complete:function(msg){
              alert (msg)   it alerts (undefined)

Comment: this one works  success :function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
               pity that I am not able to vote your answer up. but thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        myid = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
            url: "ProductsList.php",
            data: {prodID: myid},
        dataType: "json",
            complete:function(){


            window.location("ProductsList.php");
        }

    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to POST `id` , you can change:

```
...onclick="passto(this)"...
```

to

```
...onclick="passto(this.id)"...
```